Create liquidity calculation issue
In a mint position function
The calculated input is more higher while it popup in metamask.
For example , Same like uniswap calcluation I give the pair token0 = 100 , token1 = 112.068 same like calculation as parameters.
But after creating positiontomind and sending transaction in metamask popup it shows like token0 = 100 , token1 = 192+ .
Why these amount of difference.
I am using the same numbers as uniswap calculation .
export async function mintPosition(token0Amount, token1Amount, walletProvider) {
  
  try {
    let signer;
    let provider;
    if (walletProvider) {
      console.log("Connected to Wallet Connect", "Provider", walletProvider);
      provider = new BrowserProvider(walletProvider);
      signer = await provider?.getSigner();
    } else {
      console.log("connecting without walletConnect!");
      await subscribeToProviders();
      const providers =  await getProviders();
      const wallet = localStorage.getItem("walletName");
  
      const providerWithInfo = await providers.find(
        (provider) => provider.info.name === wallet
      );
      console.log("mintPosition-connectWallet", providerWithInfo);
      provider = new BrowserProvider(providerWithInfo?.provider);
      signer = await provider?.getSigner();
    }


    const address = await signer?.getAddress();

    console.log("props", token0Amount, token1Amount);
    const { poolAddress } = await findPoolAddress(
      USDT_TOKEN.address,
      XBR_TOKEN.address,
      walletProvider
    );

    const positionToMint = await constructPosition(
      CurrencyAmount.fromRawAmount(
        CurrentConfig.tokens.token0,
        fromReadableAmount(
          Number(token0Amount),
          CurrentConfig.tokens.token0.decimals
        )
      ),
      CurrencyAmount.fromRawAmount(
        CurrentConfig.tokens.token1,
        fromReadableAmount(
          Number(token1Amount),
          CurrentConfig.tokens.token1.decimals
        )
      ),
      poolAddress,
      walletProvider
    );

    // console.log("positionToIncreaseBy", positionToIncreaseBy);
    console.log("positionToMint", positionToMint);

    const mintOptions = {
      recipient: address,
      deadline: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60 * 20,
      slippageTolerance: new Percent(50, 10_000),
    };
    console.log("mintOptions", mintOptions);

    // get calldata for increasing a position
    const { calldata, value } = NonfungiblePositionManager.addCallParameters(
      // positionToIncreaseBy,
      // addLiquidityOptions
      positionToMint,
      mintOptions
    );

    const fees = await provider?.getFeeData();
    // const maxPriorityFeePerGas = await provider.getFeeData(true);

    console.log("maxFeePerGas", formatUnits(fees.maxFeePerGas, "wei"));
    console.log(
      "maxPriorityFeePerGas",
      formatUnits(fees.maxPriorityFeePerGas, "wei")
    );

    // build transaction
    const transaction = {
      data: calldata,
      to: NONFUNGIBLE_POSITION_MANAGER_CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
      value: value,
      from: address,
      maxFeePerGas: MAX_FEE_PER_GAS, 
      maxPriorityFeePerGas: MAX_PRIORITY_FEE_PER_GAS,
    };
    let gasLimit = await signer?.estimateGas(transaction);
    console.log("Estimated gas limit:",  formatUnits(gasLimit, "gwei"));
    transaction.gasLimit = gasLimit;
    console.log("transaction", transaction);

    const tx = await signer?.sendTransaction(transaction);
    
    const receipt = await tx.wait();
    // Check transaction status
    if (receipt.status === 1) {
      console.log("Transaction was successful!");
    } else {
      console.log("Transaction failed.");
    }
    console.log("receipt", receipt);
    return tx.hash;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error at minting position:", error);
    return "Failed";
  }
}

